# Parsing heap dump file

Tags: java, jvm, heap-dump, hprof

I have an application where I obviously create too many objects, i get this message:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   Dumping heap to java_pid2468.hprof ...
>   Heap dump file created [1087703293 bytes in 18.711 secs]
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

but I installed the plug in MAT, and I wanted to see how many objects i have built, and which objects occupies the most memory.
 However, when i want to parse hprof file i get this error message:

> An internal error occurred during: "Parsing heap dump from 'C:\Users\sekulicd\workspace\Csv_validation_MyIsam\java_pid2468.hprof'".
>   Java heap space

Size of hprof file is 1,087,703,293 bytes, i need answers to these questions:

1. Is parsing failed due to hprof file size?
2. Can i parse hprof file only for those projects in which does not occur error
   " java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space " ?
3. Is there any way to parse this file (1,087,703,293 bytes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try incrementing the size of the heap, it seems it's too small even for parsing the dump. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098488/jvm-heap-parameters).

Comment: My heap maximum is 371MB. Is that enough?

Comment: If you're trying to process a dump file of 1GB, the heap must be bigger than that!. Try with 1.5GB - 2 GB

Comment: I realized that, i increased heap size and it is working now fine, thank you.