# After Installing JAVA 7.1 version in z/OS OMVS I am getting below error

Tags: java

I have tried other values 1024K 512M but I am not able to run JAVA 7.1. even when I have given 256M 256M it is given as a xms too small. Kindly help me to resolve this issue

## java  -Xms512M -Xmx256M

JVMJ9GC019E -Xms too large for -Xmx
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9gc27(2): Failed to initialize
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JVM heap parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098488/jvm-heap-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

The Xmx flag specifies the maximum memory allocation pool for a JVM and Xms specifies the initial memory allocation pool. In your case, initial value could not be greater then maximum. Try to make the Xmx value greater then Xms, for example like:

```
java -Xms256M -Xmx512M
```

And I suppose, you have to read, what are [this parameters for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763095/4053652)

Comment: I tried different options with less value for Xms and greater value for Xmx but still I am getting same error.

Comment: # java -Xms128M -Xmx256M                                                        
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9gc27(2): Failed to instantiate he
ap; 256M requested                                                              
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.                               
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: take a look here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV11016 it's the same error you have this time. there is a Local fix section